# php-gd installed but gd not showing up in phpinfo on CentOS 5.3 server running nginx

Tags: php, centos, nginx, php.ini, gd

Logged in as root, I installed the php-gd libraries using

```
$ yum install php-gd
```

it said everything worked fine, so i did

```
$ /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

But the code I had been working on still complained of not having the gd libraries and when I went to check the output of `phpinfo` there was no 'gd' section.

I should note that `yum list | grep gd` shows

```
gd.i386  2.0.33-9.4.el5_1.1  installed
gd-devel.i386  2.0.33-9.4.el5_1.1  installed
gdb.i386  6.8-27.el5  installed
gdbm.i386  1.8.0-26.2.1  installed
php-gd.i386  5.1.6-23.2.el5_3  installed
```

I also added `extension=gd.so` manually to `/etc/php.ini` and it is still not showing up or raising an error which leads me to believe my php.ini is not being re-parsed when I restart nginx. Is there something outside of restarting nginx I have to do to get php.ini changes loaded?

I have a fair amount (like 3 years) of ad-hoc server administration experience although no formal training, but I'm relatively new to nginx and have never worked with CentOS before, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running PHP?  If you're running it in FCGI mode with an external spawner, restarting nginx will have no effect on the PHP server, so you'll need to restart that separately.

Comment: nevermind I found the script in /etc/init.d/fcgi-php thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Beginner linux user question:

I also am getting the "in phpinfo there was no 'gd' section" but I seem to have GD and its gd-devel installed.

How do I know if am using FCGI. Maybe I need to restart my FCGI? Goes restarting the entire computer restart FCGI?

Thanks

Comment: First, check to make sure there is a gd.so line in your php.ini, then you need to restart whatever process is executing the php. Chances are you are using a standard LAMP system so that would mean restarting apache. 

To see if fcgi is running, issue a `ps aux | grep cgi` and see if there are matching enries